# graph : php in html in php not working , how to fix it?

Tags: php, html

i need to loop the code so i tried to print it from php
i can't get it to work

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.percentbar { background:#CCCCCC; border:1px solid #666666; height:10px; 
}
.percentbar div { background: #28B8C0; height: 10px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>



<?php

$scale=1.0
$procentused[0]=3;
$scale100=$scale*100;
$cpu1g=round($procentused[0]*$scale);
echo '<div class="percentbar" style="position:relarive; width:10px; 
height:'.$scale100.'px;">';
echo '<div style="width:10px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; 
height:'.$cpu1g.'px;"></div></div>';
?></body></html>
```

I expect the output to be the vertical "usage bar"

From this code i get only background of the bar
It's modified code to be vertical from
https://joshuawinn.com/quick-and-simple-css-percentage-bar-using-php/

I don't have reputation to post img unfortunatly

---

**Edit 1:** repaired syntax errors from lukasz's answer , still not working

**Edit 2:** added more details of result

Comment: Hi, please could you add some more context to your question? What is it you are trying to achieve? Is there any more detail you could add about the expected "usage bar" And what output do you get? :)

Answer (score 0):

You have some syntax errors in your code:

```
echo '<div style="width:10px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; 
height:'.$cpu1g.'px;"</div</div>';
```

should be:

```
echo '<div style="width:10px; position: absolute; bottom: 0; 
height:'.$cpu1g.'px;"></div></div>';
```

Comment: i really cannot spot the difference between the two lines of code

Comment: Take a look at the second line in each box above, the first box has two unclosed `div` tags

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem

```
position:relarive
```

should be

```
 position:relative
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a more css + php elegant solution for the vertical bar using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox). The color area will automatically scale to the `.percentbar` element. There is no need to calculate the number of pixel of the `.used` element.

```php
<?php

// an array of percentage inputs
$percentUsedArray = [30, 20, 50, 80, 12, 19, 5, 3, 1, 0, 70, 80, 45, 56];

?>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.percentbar-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100px;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.percentbar {
  background: #CCCCCC;
  border: 1px solid #666666;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 10px;
}
.percentbar .used {
  height: 0;
  background: #28B8C0;
}
.percentbar .unused {
  flex: 1;
  background: transparent;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="percentbar-container">
    <?php foreach ($percentUsedArray as $percentUsed): ?>
      <div class="percentbar" title="<?php echo $percentUsed; ?>%">
        <div class="used" style="height: <?php echo $percentUsed; ?>%;"></div>
        <div class="unused"></div>
      </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```